# golang parsing chunked HTTP responses from socket - read chunk by chunk

Tags: http, go

My mail goal is to read data from a TCP socket connected to a HTTP server, and parse
the HTTP response chunk by chunk (Transfer-Encoding: chunked) - the server sends a chunk every 30 seconds on the same connection

I attached my code. It seems like io.Copy reads the first chunk and then waits for the next one before returning, so it blocks me.

How can I read the chunks when they arrive, without waiting for the next one?

```
func readHttpChunk(server net.conn) {
    buf := bufio.NewReader(server)
    for {
        resp, err := http.ReadResponse(buf, nil)
        b := new(bytes.Buffer)
        io.Copy(b, resp.Body)
        fmt.Printf("Got me a chunk!")
    }
}
```

Comment: You are essentially trying to use an inherently stateless protocol to stream data over and extended period of time. You will run into all sorts of problems with that approach. Instead, use [websockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) for arbitrary data, or [grpc](https://www.grpc.io/docs/quickstart/go/) for formalized messages.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I know this is a misuse of the HTTP protocol. I am still trying to solve this :)

Comment: It has been solved. See above. Reinventing the wheel over and over again does little to further FOSS and for closed source/commercial applications it is simply a waste of precious, *expensive* developer time. Especially further down the road, as you have to maintain that stuff, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `io.Copy` use `resp.Body.Read(buf)` where `buf` is an allocated byte slice. Use a big enough buffer so that the chunk doesn’t get truncated. The read should fill `buf` with a chunk.

Comment: Note that if the server reads the chunks slower than the client sends them, a fixed size buffer could be populated with parts of chunks or multiple chunks. If a chunk is a message you need to use delimiters and correctly split it server-side.